# Trying to use a java api loading so file in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to android programming.

I have a jar from which is using a .so file to do some functionality.

I want to call some APIs in this jar.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: import classes from that jar... create objects... invoke methods?

Comment: When you say "so" libraries what do you mean? If they are using other java libs then you just need to include those libs also in the build path to allow the jar you want to use to be able to use the jars it depends on.

Comment: "so" is used in Linuz instead of dlls,

Answer (score 1):

Android is just java so you import the jar to your build path and then import the classes required as normal.

This link includes information on it:
http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/02/11/java-library-jar-android/

Comment: There are some native calls happening in theses apis. While working as a general project(not android)in eclipse , i normally changes the working directory to the directory where these library files are residing. (".so") ...

Comment: Ah, right. In that case you'll have to read up on the Android Native Development Kit, since these (i assume C/C++) libs may need some modification to run on Android. http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: I dont need to compile and build the native libraries . I just need to  use it in my application . Also im doing the development on a windows machine.

Comment: No you will most likely need to recompile the native library. See Android runs on the ARM architecture, while Linux runs on the x86 architecture. If the library is native to Linux it may be using x86 specific code. To get around this use the Android Native Development Kit I mentioned above to recompile the source for the lib into a native library that will work on the ARM architecture. Atleast thats what i expect would be required, really depends on the library in question. What is it?

Comment: I don't have the source for these libraries . :(

Comment: I dropped that plan to include native libraries . As Michael said i will be facing issues with the x86 specific code. So i decided to implement it inside my code itself. The library was mainly used for xml parsing. I'm going to use DOM again .. Thanks for all the help and make me understand that it will not workout properly.